# How to support two visitors which returns different return value types in Rust?

Tags: rust, visitor-pattern

I am trying to implement a Visitor pattern in Rust.
I am not able to find a way to support two visitors which return different return value types.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=30950e47be3eebcd9557dfe5a39a7f64)

```
trait Visited<R> {
    fn accept (self: &Self, v: &dyn Visitor<R>) -> R;
}

trait Visitor<R> {
    fn visit_a(&self, a: &A<R>) -> R;
    fn visit_b(&self, b: &B) -> R;
}
```

I've implemented two data structures that can be visited.

```
// ---- A ----
struct A<R> {
    value: String,
    b: Box<dyn Visited<R>>,
}

impl<R> Visited<R> for A<R> {
    fn accept (&self, v: &dyn Visitor<R>) -> R {
        v.visit_a(self)
    }
}

// ---- B ----
struct B {
    value: i32,
}
impl<R> Visited<R> for B {
    fn accept(&self, v: &dyn Visitor<R>) -> R {
        v.visit_b(self)
    }
}
```

This worked okay when I just had a concrete visitor.

```
struct Visitor1 {}
impl Visitor<String> for Visitor1 {
    fn visit_a(&self, a: &A<String>) -> String {
        let b = a.b.accept(self);
        format!("visitor1.visit_a(): {} {}", a.value, b)
    }
    fn visit_b(&self, b: &B) -> String {
        format!("visitor1.visit_b(): {}", b.value)
    }
}
```

However, the whole point of the Visitor pattern is to let multiple algorithm to be applied against the data structure.

When I wanted to add another visitor, I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

```
struct Visitor2 {}
impl Visitor<i32> for Visitor2 {
    fn visit_a(&self, a: &A<i32>) -> i32 {
        123
    }
    fn visit_b(&self, b: &B) -> i32 {
        456
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {
        value: "HELLO".to_string(),
        b: Box::new(B{ value: 32 })
    };
    let v1 = Visitor1{};
    let s: String = a.accept(&v1);
    println!("{}", s);

    let v2 = Visitor2{};
    let v: i32 = a.accept(&v2);
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

The type of `a` is inferred as `A<String>`, and the `a.accept(&v2)` caused a type mismatch error.

I'd like to tell `a` to be visited by `Visitor1` and `Visitor2`.  How can I do this?

Comment: You can type-erase `Visited` and `Visitor`, but this requires some work and converting the generic parameter to an associated type.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Doesn't seem straight forward to me, would you care to elaborate? The `Box<dyn Visited>` is the problem, it can't be crated when you convert `accept` to `accept<R>`. Maybe I'm going down the wrong path, though.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Does my answer go in the direction you thought of?

Comment: @Finomnis No. If I will have time I will write an answer.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Well, that's how I would do it :) I'm curious to see your solution, though. I currently can't see a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return only `'static` types, you can use [type erasure](https://www.thecodedmessage.com/posts/erased-serde/). The idea is to create a trait, `ErasedVisitor`, that is not generic and instead return `Box<dyn Any>`, and implement this trait for all `Visitor`s and use it internally. This mean, though, that you cannot use a generic parameter, only an associated type (otherwise you get "unconstrained type parameter":

```rust
trait Visited {
    fn accept_dyn(&self, v: &dyn ErasedVisitor) -> Box<dyn Any>;
    fn accept<V: Visitor>(&self, v: &V) -> V::Result
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        *self.accept_dyn(v).downcast().unwrap()
    }
}

impl<T: ?Sized + Visited> Visited for &'_ T {
    fn accept_dyn(&self, v: &dyn ErasedVisitor) -> Box<dyn Any> {
        T::accept_dyn(&**self, v)
    }
}

impl<T: ?Sized + Visited> Visited for &'_ mut T {
    fn accept_dyn(&self, v: &dyn ErasedVisitor) -> Box<dyn Any> {
        T::accept_dyn(&**self, v)
    }
}

impl<T: ?Sized + Visited> Visited for Box<T> {
    fn accept_dyn(&self, v: &dyn ErasedVisitor) -> Box<dyn Any> {
        T::accept_dyn(&**self, v)
    }
}

trait Visitor {
    type Result: 'static;
    fn visit_a(&self, a: &A) -> Self::Result;
    fn visit_b(&self, b: &B) -> Self::Result;
}

trait ErasedVisitor {
    fn visit_a(&self, a: &A) -> Box<dyn Any>;
    fn visit_b(&self, b: &B) -> Box<dyn Any>;
}

impl<V: ?Sized + Visitor> ErasedVisitor for V {
    fn visit_a(&self, a: &A) -> Box<dyn Any> {
        Box::new(<Self as Visitor>::visit_a(self, a))
    }
    fn visit_b(&self, b: &B) -> Box<dyn Any> {
        Box::new(<Self as Visitor>::visit_b(self, b))
    }
}

struct A {
    value: String,
    b: Box<dyn Visited>,
}

impl Visited for A {
    fn accept_dyn(&self, v: &dyn ErasedVisitor) -> Box<dyn Any> {
        v.visit_a(self)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d811408fb12159778b04cff10b68ffb7).

But if you can, the best way is to use static polymorphism (generics) instead of dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Interesting! Cool pattern. Although I kind of dislike the fact that if this is exposed to a user who implements `Visited` for his own types, he is capable of creating a runtime error by returning something weird from `accept_dyn`.

Comment: @Finomnis Yes, the type erasure pattern with return types is... not great. It works better with parameters.

Comment: It worked!  It is quite complicated and it seems better not to implement the Visitor with the variable return value.  I've learned several new techniques with the answer, though!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `Visited` trait to support multiple return types, you cannot tie the return type to the object itself. Currently, the return type is a generic, so every object has the return type hard-coded into it.

To solve this, you can remove the return type generic from the `Visited` trait and instead attach it to the `accept` function.

This has one drawback though: You can no longer create trait objects with this trait. That makes sense, because once cast to a `dyn Visited`, Rust no longer knows which type it is, making it impossible for the compiler to compile the `accept` function for all required types. It looses the knowledge between the compilated function and the types that it will get called with.

Normally, this is fine, but in your case, `A` holds a `Box<dyn Visited>`. This is impossible, due to the reasons described above.

So if we change `Box<dyn Visited>` to `B`, (and do some refactoring with the generics), we can get it to work:

```rust
trait Visited {
    fn accept<V: Visitor>(&self, v: &V) -> V::Ret;
}

trait Visitor {
    type Ret;
    fn visit_a(&self, a: &A) -> Self::Ret;
    fn visit_b(&self, b: &B) -> Self::Ret;
}

// ---- A ----
struct A {
    value: String,
    b: B,
}

impl Visited for A {
    fn accept<V: Visitor>(&self, v: &V) -> V::Ret {
        v.visit_a(self)
    }
}

// ---- B ----
struct B {
    value: i32,
}
impl Visited for B {
    fn accept<V: Visitor>(&self, v: &V) -> V::Ret {
        v.visit_b(self)
    }
}

struct Visitor1 {}
impl Visitor for Visitor1 {
    type Ret = String;
    fn visit_a(&self, a: &A) -> String {
        let b = a.b.accept(self);
        format!("visitor1.visit_a(): {} {}", a.value, b)
    }
    fn visit_b(&self, b: &B) -> String {
        format!("visitor1.visit_b(): {}", b.value)
    }
}

struct Visitor2 {}
impl Visitor for Visitor2 {
    type Ret = i32;
    fn visit_a(&self, _a: &A) -> i32 {
        123
    }
    fn visit_b(&self, _b: &B) -> i32 {
        456
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {
        value: "HELLO".to_string(),
        b: B { value: 32 },
    };
    let v1 = Visitor1 {};
    let s: String = a.accept(&v1);
    println!("{}", s);

    let v2 = Visitor2 {};
    let v: i32 = a.accept(&v2);
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

```
visitor1.visit_a(): HELLO visitor1.visit_b(): 32
123
```

We can make this a little more convenient and make the actual type a generic of `A`. In contrast to a `dyn Visited`, this allows Rust to resolve its exact type at compile time, making it possible to compile it.

```rust
trait Visited {
    fn accept<V: Visitor>(&self, v: &V) -> V::Ret;
}

trait Visitor {
    type Ret;
    fn visit_a<T: Visited>(&self, a: &A<T>) -> Self::Ret;
    fn visit_b(&self, b: &B) -> Self::Ret;
}

// ---- A ----
struct A<T> {
    value: String,
    b: T,
}

impl<T: Visited> Visited for A<T> {
    fn accept<V: Visitor>(&self, v: &V) -> V::Ret {
        v.visit_a(self)
    }
}

// ---- B ----
struct B {
    value: i32,
}
impl Visited for B {
    fn accept<V: Visitor>(&self, v: &V) -> V::Ret {
        v.visit_b(self)
    }
}

struct Visitor1 {}
impl Visitor for Visitor1 {
    type Ret = String;
    fn visit_a<T: Visited>(&self, a: &A<T>) -> String {
        let b = a.b.accept(self);
        format!("visitor1.visit_a(): {} {}", a.value, b)
    }
    fn visit_b(&self, b: &B) -> String {
        format!("visitor1.visit_b(): {}", b.value)
    }
}

struct Visitor2 {}
impl Visitor for Visitor2 {
    type Ret = i32;
    fn visit_a<T: Visited>(&self, _a: &A<T>) -> i32 {
        123
    }
    fn visit_b(&self, _b: &B) -> i32 {
        456
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {
        value: "HELLO".to_string(),
        b: B { value: 32 },
    };
    let v1 = Visitor1 {};
    let s: String = a.accept(&v1);
    println!("{}", s);

    let v2 = Visitor2 {};
    let v: i32 = a.accept(&v2);
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

```
visitor1.visit_a(): HELLO visitor1.visit_b(): 32
123
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.  The original code needed to be able to refer other types than B (`struct C`, `struct D`), and I was looking for a solution that can have one of `B`/`C`/`D` or even `A`.

Comment: Well, that's why I added the section about the generic. You can use that to be one of the others. If you want it to be `A`, you need to box it again to prevent a circular dependency, but I don't see how this would be a problem with my solution. I still think it's the better way to go.

Comment: Can we do it dynamically?  The original code's data structure was AST and the structure was one of different kind of expressions which is generated dynamically.  So, A's child could be B or C depends on the parsed input.  Does this work in that case?

Comment: Hmmm ... I'm afraid not. I guess you are right. Although if that is the case, you could still go down the `enum` Route. Do you know what types are possible beforehand? If yes, you could implement something similar to [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html) to resolve it at runtime without the possibility of a type error, and then implement `Visited` for that enum. Enums are typically used for multiple-outcome parsing results, like seen in `serde_json`. But yes, you could of course use the type-erasure way layed out by @ChayimFriedman.

Comment: I just personally don't really like dynamic type casting because (in my opinion) it goes against the spirit of the Rust programming language in general. But that is of course opinionated and everyone is free to have a different opinion.